# How do you develop a plugin for Microsoft Excel that is available for download (not from the Excel marketplace)?

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

We are trying to develop a plugin for Excel, but apparently you can only have it available through the Excel Add-in Store, which requires tedious partnerships.

Does anybody know of a way to get a user to download a plugin and have it available in their local Excel installation? Similar to plugins for other apps (like Notepad++)?

Using Yeoman generator as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-quickstart-jquery?tabs=yeomangenerator

Comment: Are you using C#?

Comment: No using javascript, as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-quickstart-jquery?tabs=yeomangenerator @JohnPeters

Answer (score 0):

Unlike COM add-ins, Office Add-ins don't involve code that runs on the user's device or in the Office client. For an Office Add-in, the host application, for example Excel, reads the add-in manifest and hooks up the add-in’s custom ribbon buttons and menu commands in the UI.

Therefore Office Web Add-in includes two basic components: an XML manifest file, and your own web application. The manifest defines various settings, including how your add-in integrates with Office clients. Your web application needs to be hosted on a web server, or web hosting service, such as Microsoft Azure.

So the add-in code will not be installed in the local machine.
Therefore The manifest file of an Office Add-in describes how your add-in should be activated when an end-user installs and uses it with Office documents and applications.

Therefore, the following solutions are available for the user to get the add-in
[image]

For more information, you could refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish) document

Comment: you want to say that JavaScript is not running on the user's device or in the Office client, right? Where is it running then?

Comment: Is it possible to do it another way like I asked? I have excel plugins that I have downloaded from places other than the add in store